# Want to test Bonjour with 2 iphone/ipad

Tags: bonjour

Apologies for such a silly question.

Please note I don't have Apple TV or any printer. I would like to get hold of the packet trace that takes place when bonjour (Discovery and Resolution phase) is in action. I need to get bonjour into action using just 2 iphone/ipad (I have a Wifi Network through which I could connect these iPad/iPod). Please suggest what application can I use to achieve this? I am a newbie in iOS world, and have no idea of apps related to bonjour.

Hope some of you could help.